# How do I handle the Start Event for SlideToggle?

Tags: jquery

I'm reading the documentation for slidetoggle, and I can see there's an event for start event: http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/ - but I can't seem to find a way to use this. Any assisting hand on this matter?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Pass it as option: http://jsfiddle.net/y7f1ht8j/  Now it would be easier to help if you provide your code in question

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation. Worked well! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many thanks for the help.

The correct way to do this is:

```
$('div').slideToggle({
   duration: 800,
   start: function(){
      console.log('start anim')
   },
   done: function() {
      console.log('end anim')
   }
})
```

Credits @A. Wolff

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of using `slide toggle`

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>

div#mydiv
{
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 background-color: orange;
 display: none;
}
</style>

<body>

<h3>This is how slideToggle works</h3>
<button id="mybutton">SlideDown OR SlideUp</button>
<div id='mydiv'></div>



<script type="text/javascript">

$("#mybutton").click(function(){
 $("#mydiv").slideToggle(1000);
});





</script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Explanation**

actually what `slideToggle` does is it does the both `slideUp` and `slideDown` together. if the `div` or any other `element` is in `slideUp` mode it does `slidDown` or else if the the `div` is in `slideDown` mode it does `slideUp`. basically if you do not use this  `slideToggle`, you have to write two functions to `slideUp` and `slideDown` or you have to use a `callback` funtion to do it.so this make easy to do us these type things.

hope this will help to you.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but my question was concerning how to handle the start event on slidetoggle (which was answered by A. Wolff above). :)

Comment: what to you meant by start evnet, do you mean how your element should when start or any other.

Comment: What I mean with start event is when the slideToggle event is fired (meaning, asap the anim is started)